# How to hide back status bar in splashscreen

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, splash-screen

I have hid the status bar and action bar in theme.xml file. But my splashscreen has a black status bar and the navigation bar. How to get rid of that. Please share your thoughts.

```
<style
    name="SplashTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the status bar by

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

the navigationbar can be hidden by

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

Note - when user interacts with the screen the navigationbar reappers

You can use this code in your on create before super.onCreate

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Read more : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity,MainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        },2000)
    }
```

//Use this to hide the status bar of your activity
`window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`

//use this to reable status bar for your rest of the activity otherwise it wont be shown in all activity

```
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: Int FLAG_FULLSCREEN is deprecated and I used this approach, it didn't worked.

Comment: i gave you this snippet of code from my running project it was working to me!

anyways good luck!

Comment: Sorry bro it didn't work for me, Anyways thankyou for sharing your snippet.